# Accessing HTML input fields with javascript - spaces in input name

Tags: javascript

I'm adding some javascript validation to a form. The form has fields that currently look like:

```
<input name="Employee Full Name" value="" type="text" id="Employee Full Name" size="30" maxlength="50" style="width:300px;">
```

I am trying to access the values of the fields, but I seem to be doing it incorrectly with the spaces in the input name, is there a way to escape?

```
if (theForm.Employee Full Name.value == ""){   
   alert("Please enter a value for the \"Employee Full Name\" field.");     
   theForm.Employee Full Name.focus();   
   return (false);   
}
```

Comment: Please just use underscore or whatever, you avoid a lot of trouble and bugs not instantly apparent and there is no additional effort or drawbacks. :( This applies for any attribute (id as well)

Comment: I concur with your comments, however, I was not given approval to change the element names on the forms. :(

Comment: `camelCaseIsYourFriend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bracket notation for objects as well as arrays:

```
theForm['Employee Full Name'].value == ""
```

This allows you to access attributes where the names are invalid in a `.` notation syntax:

```
foo.1 //foo['1']
foo.this-is-wrong //foo['this-is-wrong']
foo.bar.baz //although this looks correct, it's wrong if you actually wanted foo['bar.baz']
```

Answer (score 1):

Contain them within square braces, using quotes.

```
if (theForm["Employee Full Name"]value == ""){   
   alert("Please enter a value for the \"Employee Full Name\" field.");     
   theForm.["Employee Full Name"].focus();   
   return false;
}
```

Every JavaScript object can also be referenced in this way. For instance, all of the following methods have the same result:

```
window.location.href
window["location"].href
window.location["href"]
window["location"]['href'] //Single quotes / double quotes don't matter.
```