# simple onclick doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have found this great code snippets on this [blog](http://blog.oscarcp.com/?p=163) to change the language selector for something more stylish. (Twitter-bootstrap in mind)

It looks pretty neat, however when I actually click on the selection, nothing is submitted on **onclick**.  I am not yet an expert in jquery, but could something have been deprecated in latest 1.8.0 version that stops the `onclick` from working?

```
<form name="setLang{{ lang.1}}" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
   <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}" />
   <a href="#" onclick="document.setLang{{ lang.1 }}.submit(); return false;">{{ lang.1 }}</a>
</form>
```

Comment: are you missing parentheses in the `setLang` (e.g. `document.setLang({{ lang.1 }}).submit(); return false;`)?

Comment: sorry I changed the tag to javascript, so no one is offended. ;-)

Comment: Aren't those double-braces indicative of a [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) template? If so, they'll be replaced with an actual value upon display of the template…

Comment: that's right. Its Django. :) The problem was indeed javascript. See below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `document.setLang{{ lang.1 }}` to get the `form`. That's **not** a valid name for a DOM element. JavaScript will break processing at the first whitespace it encounters, and throw an error.

I strongly suggest you use a valid `name` value, but if you really need to keep using that, you can access the element with `document.getElementsByName("setLang{{ lang.1}}")[0].submit()`.​​​​

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your form name has spaces in it means you can't access the form item in the DOM the way you are intending to.  I would give the form an id that doesn't contain spaces and access it that way.

```
<form name="setLang{{ lang.1}}" id="setLang" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
   <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}" />
   <a href="#" onclick="document.setLang.submit(); return false;">{{ lang.1 }}</a>
</form>
```

Also, see here:  [Accessing HTML input fields with javascript - spaces in input name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038274/accessing-html-input-fields-with-javascript-spaces-in-input-name)